# Is there any way to Customize alertbox in HTML?

Tags: html, cordova

I want to customize the default look of alert boxes which generally shows in any browser. Is there any way to customize according to my choice?

I found this [link](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-notification-plugin-example.html).

Actually i want to customize alert boxes so that i can use it using PHONEGAP

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't style alert boxes. If you want to style popups use modal windows.